# Can this conventional router be added in a mesh network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, mesh-networking

The [Cudy WR1300](http://www.cudytech.com/productinfo/90088.html) is a conventional dual-band router, while the [Cudy M1200](https://www.cudy.com/productinfo/1009967.html) is a dedicated mesh router. Now, the question is, can these two routers be used together in a mesh system to provide seamless roaming capabilities?

Comment: Check if WR1300 can work with mesh network (some routers can). If not - you can't, you can have two separate WiFi networks

Answer (score 1):

Seamless roaming doesn't require mesh topology wireless backhauls, or any coordination between APs (wireless routers) for that matter. They don't even have to be from the same vendor. As long as you can connect your WR1300 into your home network (perhaps via Ethernet), you can put it in AP (i.e. not NAT) mode and give it the same SSID, wireless security type, and wireless password as your existing wireless network, and your clients will seamlessly roam to the new AP when it appears to be their best choice.